# ionic composent place change

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Every time I run the app the `-` and `+` components are on a different baseline or vertical offset than the text.

[image: this is what happens when I run the app]

**this is my ionic html page** { I pasted only one row the others are the same }

```html
<ion-grid class="filters" no-padding margin-top>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col class="adult" width-70>
      <span ion-text color="primary"><strong>BusinessDate</strong>
            </span>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-10 text-center>
      <ion-icon name="remove-circle" class="text-2x" tappable color="secondary">
      </ion-icon>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-10 text-center>{{businessdate}}</ion-col>
    <ion-col width-10 text-center>
      <ion-icon name="add-circle" class="text-2x" tappable color="secondary">
      </ion-icon>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "change the place"?

Comment: when i change the device , the - component also the + are in the same line and in other device are like you see there